# Is the "profile" package part of python standard distribution?

Tags: python, profiler

I just noticed that the `import profile` fails on my Ubuntu Linux box that has Python 2.6.4 installed. This surprised me because I thought it was part of the standard Python distribution.

It turned out I needed to install the `python-profiler` Debian package to get the `profile` package. My question is, should I expect `profile` to exist in a Python installation? If not, is there a PyPi package for it that I can depend on in my `setup.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python says `profile` should always exist in a Python installation, but there are some [license problems](http://bugs.python.org/issue12417) that kept it from being included in Debian's, and thus in Ubuntu's main/universe repositories. So it has to live in another package, and there's no PyPI alternative for it since Python includes it.

It's probably best to tell your Debian/Ubuntu users to install `python-profiler` manually. Since profiling is a feature that's only really useful for programmers, hopefully it won't inconvenience them too much.

The copyright holders (Disney) have changed the license recently, so the problem will eventually go away.

Answer (score 4):

The `profile` module is part of standard Python (and is different from `cProfile` as it is implemented purely in Python), but Ubuntu doesn't install it by default likely because of its Debian lineage. `profile` isn't default included in Debian either, because `profile.py` has a different license from the rest of Python.

The license doesn't conform to the Debian Free Software Guidelines: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=293932

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be called cProfile, may be try

```
try:
    import profile
except:
    import cProfile as profile
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. According to the [Python Profilers page](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) "profile, a pure Python module whose interface is imitated by cProfile.". Good to know!